# Setting small interval on LineAxis

Tags: apache-flex, mxml, bar-chart

I am having a problem setting up the LinearAxis in a horizontal BarChart using an interval value that is 0.25.  I am using a minimum value of 0.0 and a maximum of 1.0

This is the way it's currently rendering:

[image]

Is there a way to force the breaks at 0.25?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it is doing it right... You have the tick interval set as 0.25 but it is rounding the value for you.  How nice of it :)

I think you want to set the `maximumLabelPrecision` to avoid this silliness.

```
<mx:horizontalAxis>
    <mx:LinearAxis interval="0.25" maximumLabelPrecision="2" /> 
</mx:horizontalAxis>
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy.  I guess I didn't look through the API deep enough. Thanks.